# Is there a way to control JPA cascade delete ordering?

Tags: java, jpa

I'm using barebones JPA with Hibernate as a provider--I'm not using any Hibernate-specific functionality. I have an entity with a `@ManyToMany` field that maps to another two-column MtM table, `Groups`, and `CASCADE DELETE` is specified for the fields of this MtM table.

The delete cascading all works fine. The issue comes when I need to remove one of my entity from the database:

```
    String jpql = "DELETE FROM Entity e WHERE e.id = :id AND :g MEMBER OF e.groups"
    Query tq = em.createQuery(jpql);
    tq.setParameter("id", 42);
    tq.setParameter("g", myGroup);
    long rows = tq.executeUpdate();
    if (rows == 0) throw new Exception();
```

The second condition of the above query will always be false, it seems, because the Entity's MtM `entity_group` entry is deleted before the Entity's deletion occurs. If I turn on query logging, I'll see something like:

```
delete from **entity_group** where (entity_id) in (select id from entity where id=?)
delete from entity where id=? and (? in (select groups1_.group_id from **entity_group** groups1_ where entity.id=groups1_.entity_id))
```

Is there any way to control the ordering of what is deleted when? I'd really like to perform these cascaded deletes AFTER the main delete so that conditionals aren't useless. I also really don't want to take this logic out of the DB layer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, it is better to first select id of the entity you want to remove, and then issue a second JPQL query to delete entity with this specific id.

The behavior you observed is specific to your JPA provider and I guess there is little to do about it. Or the solution is too complicated and non-portable, that it is not worth it.

Note that ordering would not work. If you first delete Entity before groups, you loose references to related groups. In most cases deleting entity would even fail due to foreign key constraints.